# Reliability of using FFMPEG in IOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, app-store, video-processing

***What i am trying to do:***

Trying to develop an **Enterprise** level **IOS** application with **FFMPEG** for video Processing.

***What i have done so far:***

Created a Linux based sample program with FFMPEG and made it work. Learnt how to use FFMPEG. I have already found the **build instructions** to build the FFMPEG packages 
   for IOS.

***What help i need:***

Does apple **allow** to place the **FFMPEG** based application in **IOS Application Store**?

As there is no **official** support from **ffmpeg community** for IOS, how **reliable** the "FFMPEG-IOS" is, as i don't want to get into any problems in future especially when apple releases a new version of os or the problem of ffmpeg only with IOS?

Comment: do you have any tutorials on how you built it together and integrated with a native app?  I'm still learning and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe several users here have apps in the App Store that are compiled and linked with ffmpeg. I personally am going to submit my app within the next month. I anticipate that it will be accepted.

For iOS, you cannot dynamically link. You must statically link. Therefore, the ffmpeg libraries will be part of your app. It would be highly unlikely that a future iOS update would break the code. Your app is more likely to break for some other reason unrelated to ffmpeg, e.g. a UI change, that Apple makes.

The requirement for static linking means that you must understand the ffmpeg licensing situation carefully. I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice. You should consult a lawyer for real legal advice. Some people interpret the LGPL to mean that static linking is OK as long as you do not modify the ffmpeg source code and you distribute the ffmpeg source code (e.g., provide it for download on your server) as well as the static library (.a) files used in building your app. You must also credit the ffmpeg project for your use of their code. More information: http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have built the latest ffmpeg for iOS. Can you give me some tutorials or a few sample codes to start with ffmpeg. As i am learning objective C, any help would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi njahnke, Have you commit your app with ffmpeg to AppStore successful after your answer last year? We are concerning same issue about releasing app to AppStore.

Comment: @njahnke do you some sample application of how to use ffmpeg in iOS  or any link that can help me. I just don't understand how to use that stuff.